# Как обратится к массиву в динамической функции

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том что название (не массив!) массива передается в динамическую функцию и нужно из этого массива прочитать значения. Функция примерно такая:

var getFromTable = new Function  ('index', 'arr', 'property', 'return arr[index][property]');

Вызов выглядит так:

var c = getFromTable (1, 'materials', 'width');

Ожидаемо, что все это не работает, но как сделать чтоб сработало?

Answer (score 1):

Суть в следующем :
чтобы не испорльзовать eval сделаем 1н обьект, который будет хранить все таблицы, названия таблиц будут названиями свойств обьекта, а значениями етих свойств будут масивы/данные етих таблиц, в таком случаи данные легко достать с общего масива и легко добавить новые или удалить старые

Пример такого кода :

```js
'use strict';

var tabels = {
 tab1 : [
 {prop1 : "p1",
  prop12 : "p12"},
 {prop2 : "p2"},
 {prop3 : "p3"}
 ],
  tab2 : [
 {prop1 : "p1"},
 {prop2 : "p2"},
 {prop3 : "p3"}
 ]
};
   
function getFromTable(index, arr, property){
 return tabels[arr][index][property];
};
   
console.log(getFromTable(0,'tab1','prop12'));
```

Answer (score 0):

ну например так...

```js
var materials = [
  {width: 10}, {width: 20}, {width: 30}
]

function getFromTable(i, arr, prop) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) throw "second arg must be arr";
  if (!arr[i]) throw "no index in arr";
  if (!arr[i][prop]) throw "no prop in index arr";;
  return arr[i][prop];
}

console.log(getFromTable(2, materials, 'width'));
```

Если же вам необходимо передавать название массива как строку, что меня очень смущает и я не могу представить себе прикладную задачу для решения которой это необходимо делать, то вам может придти на помощь eval() но помните что это очень плохая практика.

```js
var materials = [{width: 10}, {width: 20}]

function getFromTable(i, arr, property) {
  var execCmd = arr + '[' + i + ']' + '["' + property + '"]';
  return eval(execCmd);
}

console.log(getFromTable(1, 'materials', 'width'));
```

Comment: Немного не то. 'Arr' передается в динамическую функцию как строка. Т.е. просто название массива. Иначе же никак? Соответственно задача в том, чтоб из строки-названия сделать ссылку на реальный массив.

Comment: объясните зачем передавать вместо массива его название, при какой прикладной задаче такое может быть необходимо?

Comment: Данные хранятся в разных таблицах (массивах) и в зависимости от условий идет обращение к разным массивам. Кажется я Вас понял. На самом деле нет необходимости делать разные таблицы, разумнее хранить все данные в одной.

Comment: отредактировал ответ, но обратите внимание что использование eval - это очень плохая практика.

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант работает.

Comment: если это так, то есть смысл принять ответ.

Comment: как вариант можно создать обьект в котором свойства будут "таблицами-масивами"  и обращаться к определенному свойству нужной таблицы по названиям, без использования eval :
    obj['table name'][1]['property name']